# I have created a view. But I want to call it from my database instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my view. And i have run it in msdb. I have a database name 'mytest'

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[vwconfirmEmailSent]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[vwconfirmEmailSent]
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwconfirmEmailSent]
AS
SELECT sa.recipients, sa.sent_status, sa.sent_date
FROM  sysmail_allitems sa
LEFT join sysmail_sentitems ss ON ss.mailitem_id = sa.mailitem_id
LEFT JOIN sysmail_unsentitems su ON ss.mailitem_id = su.mailitem_id
```

When i used 
select * from [dbo].[vwconfirmEmailSent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select from a view in another database you must fully qualify it, 
[database].[schema].[objectname]

```
select * from [msdb].[dbo].[vwconfirmEmailSent]
```